# Looping throught XML element to add data

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I dont know how exactly to word my question, so apologies from up front. I have an xml file and it has elements like the following:

```
- <Allow_BenGrade>
  <Amount BenListID="0">0</Amount> 
  </Allow_BenGrade>
- <Add_Earnings_NonTaxable>
  <Amount AddEarnID="0">0</Amount> 
  </Add_Earnings_NonTaxable>
```

I am interested in **Allow_BenGrade** where i can add multiple elements inside there. I have list of 3 items but when I loop through to write it to the file, it only writes the last item in the list, so instead of have 3 elements inside **Allow_BenGrade**, i end up having one (last one in the item list). My code is below. Please help thank you.

```
var query = from nm in xelement.Elements("EmployeeFinance")
                                    select new Allowance {
                                    a_empersonalID = (int)nm.Element("EmpPersonal_Id"),
                                    a_allbengradeID = (int)nm.Element("Grade_Id")
                           };
                var x = query.ToList();


                foreach (var xEle in x)
                {
                    var qryBenListGrade = from ee in context.Employee_Employ
                                 join abg in context.All_Inc_Ben_Grade
                                 on ee.Grade_Id equals abg.GradeID
                                 join abl in context.All_Inc_Ben_Listing
                                 on abg.All_Inc_Ben_ListingID equals abl.ID
                                 where ee.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id == xEle.a_empersonalID && abg.GradeID == xEle.a_allbengradeID && (abl.Part_of_basic == "N" && abl.Status == "A" && abl.Type_of_earnings == 2)
                                 //abl.Approved_on !=null &&
                                 select new 
                                 {
                                        abl.ID,
                                        abl.Amount,
                                        abg.GradeID,
                                        ee.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id,
                                        abl.Per_Non_Taxable,
                                        abl.Per_Taxable
                                 };
                    var y = qryBenListGrade.ToList();
                    //xEle.a_Amount = 0;
                    foreach (var tt in y)
                    {
                   Debug.WriteLine("amount: " + tt.Amount + " emp id: " + tt.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id + " ben list id: " + tt.ID);
                       // xEle.a_Amount = xEle.a_Amount + tt.Amount;

                        var result = from element in doc.Descendants("EmployeeFinance")
                                     where int.Parse(element.Element("EmpPersonal_Id").Value) == tt.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id
                                     select element;
                        foreach (var ele in result)
                        {
                            ele.Element("Allow_BenGrade").SetElementValue("Amount", tt.Amount);
                            //ele.Element("Allow_BenGrade").Element("Amount").SetAttributeValue("BenListID", tt.ID);
                        }

                    }
                    doc.Save(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetElementValue` will, as the name suggests, set the value of the `Amount` element... You need to Add a new one instead:

```
ele.Element("Allow_BenGrade").Add(new XElement("Amount", 
                                      new XAttribute("BenListID", tt.ID),
                                      tt.Amount);
```

Let me know if that solves it for you.

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [XElement.SetElementValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setelementvalue.aspx):

> Sets the value of a child element, adds a child element, or removes a
>   child element.

Also:

> The value is assigned to the first child element with the specified
>   name. If no child element with the specified name exists, a new child
>   element is added. If the value is null, the first child element with
>   the specified name, if any, is deleted.
>
> This method does not add child nodes or attributes to the specified
>   child element.

You should use the [XElement.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add.aspx) instead.